# Can't take file names with spaces in shell script for loop

Tags: bash, shell, zip

I am trying to take filenames with spaces
Get them into a for loop
zip each file
Once zipped, remove the original using below:

```
for appdir in $(ls /home/location/$dirname); do

  for logFile in $(find /home/location/$dirname/$appdir -type f -mtime +10 \( ! -iname "*.zip" ! -iname "*.gz" \)); do
    echo $logFile
```

Files I am trying to zip which has spaces:

```
/home/location/hdd1/domain/servername/EXT1/ET SOME To FILENAME/xml/sdlfkd.xml
/home/location/hdd1/domain/servername/EXT1/ET SOME To FILENAME2/xml/sd2fkd.xml
```

I know filenames with spaces can be made into a single filename like below -

```
find /location/$appdir -type f -mtime +10  -print0 | xargs -0 ls
```

The actual zip command which takes the filename from the "for" condition comes later to take each file, makes a zip and removes the original one.

I get below error for zip command:

```
[stdout: 4]                           zip warning: name not matched: ET
zip error: Nothing to do! (ET.zip)
[stdout: 4]           SOME
[stdout: 4]                           zip warning: name not matched: SOME
zip error: Nothing to do! (SOME.zip)
```

How can I modify the condition where I can provide entire filename each time to the "for" loop so it then proceeds to zip each file and goes further?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use `double quotes` around your file variables.

Comment: See [BashFAQ #20: How can I find and safely handle file names containing newlines, spaces or both?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020) and [BashFAQ: Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Answer (score 1):

Always use double quotes when manipulating files.

See for example the code below will create one unique file called a b c :

```
will /home/will/a # touch "a b c"
will /home/will/a # ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r--    1 root     system            0 Sep 21 08:47 a b c
```

But this will create 3 different files called, a, b and c

```
will /home/will/a # touch a b c
will /home/will/a # ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r--    1 root     system            0 Sep 21 08:47 a
-rw-r--r--    1 root     system            0 Sep 21 08:47 b
-rw-r--r--    1 root     system            0 Sep 21 08:47 c
```

So now imagine I would be not creating but deleting or altering those files, it could be much more harmful if files name were not the ones expected.

In your case I would try this :

```
   for appdir in $(ls "/home/location/$dirname"); do

  for logFile in $(find "/home/location/$dirname/$appdir" -type f -mtime +10 \( ! -iname "*.zip" ! -iname "*.gz" \)); do
    echo "$logFile"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `for appdir in $(somecommand)` will split on spaces, just like unquoted variables will. Handling arbitrary filenames in the shell is tricky, but there are ways to do it; see [BashFAQ #20: How can I find and safely handle file names containing newlines, spaces or both?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020).